# Clicking one button 5 times or more then activate another button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to activate second button after some 5 or more clicks on first one. How can I do this.

```
$(function(){
    $("#bt1").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");

    });
});
```

Comment: You can track the btn#1 click counts through session storage. Once the count reaches 5, you can enable btn#2

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
var cnt = 0;
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  cnt++;
  console.log(cnt); //remove this line to not see the count
  if(cnt >= 5) {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#btn2").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" disabled>Button 2</button>
```

Comment: np, if that is everything, please close the question (accept an answer)